# How to extract view from OpenGL to video stream?

Tags: opengl, rendering, viewpoint

In my software, I am performing a rendering of a fused point cloud in OpenGL. Is it possible to access the result of the rendering in the form of a video stream (e.g. H264 video)?

Comment: A simple (relatively speaking) implementation could use [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) to read frames and [`ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org/) (or associated libraries) to encode those frames.

Comment: I can't get it to work, any other ideas?